# Microsoft Custom Speech Service (CRIS)

Tags: speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I am doing POC with the CRIS we are building a voiceBot and want to train our bot for dynamic conditions and real time scenarios.

As mentioned in CRIS we can overcome the background noise barrier by building a custom acoustic model, I want to achieve the same.

I build 2 custom speech models based on ~4.5 hours of length.
First model was based on clean audio files with no background noise.
Second model was based on same audio files with noise superimposed on them.

The language in context is plain English with no specific vocabulary.

The dataset were same for both the models the only difference is that in dataset for second model all the files superimposed with a static background noise.

I ran the accuracy test based on audio files superimposed with noise but the results were strange.
The second model gave me WER of 93%  & first model a WER of 100% which is really strange to me as the first model being trained for background noises rather than first model, by theory second model should give less WER as compare to first model.

As I can't see in CRIS what's happening behind the scene, I want to know does CRIS gives effective results with background noises or its really effective, if yes then what I am doing wrong as I tried multiple times same results.

Comment: Exactly the reason to use open source ASR. At least you might figure out what happens on background. You can start with https://github.com/achernetsov/asr-server or with https://github.com/achernetsov/kaldi-docker-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, 93% WER is extremely high and can only happen if you barely understand the audio when listening to it.

what I understand is that you created 3 data sets:

- training_1: 4.5 hours of clean audio
- training_2: 4.5 hours of noisy audio
- test_1: few minutes of noisy audio

I assume that the noise is similar in training_2 and test_1. NB: You cannot add artificial noise to training_2 and use real noise in test_1. Training data has to be representative of test data.

If I get it right, when you decode audio in test_1 with the model trained with training_1, you get 93% WER. When you decode test_1 with the model trained with training_2, you get 100% WER. What WER do you get if you decode test_1 with our baseline model (Microsoft Conversational Model)? You can simply create a new accuracy test to get this value.

If you want to share more details and data, please contact us (link at bottom of https://cris.ai/). We can have a closer look at what is going wrong.

Thanks for your interest in Custom Speech Service.

Comment: i tested the test files with Microsoft Conversational Model and i got 97.2% WER.